# Locating mail users and setup for RT

Tags: postfix, email

We have an AD where I work which handles usernames/email, authentication etc and all the rest.  I've been trying to find our 'support' email address on there but soon realised that it exists not on the AD server, but on a CentOS (5.2) server running Request Tracker (RT).  However, I can't actually find the configuration files/settings for this email add as I want to remove some forwarding settings etc. but am unsure where to look or how to work out what mail service I'm running, and where the crucial files are stored.

All I've found so far is a fairly large text file with all the received emails in /var/mail.  I've ran programs like top, ps to see if I can find if any mail application is running, but nothing stood out to me.  I do know that postfix is installed on this server and have been searching the config files in /etc/postfix but it seems that mail isn't set with postfix on this box...

I know next to nothing about Linux and mail, so any help is appreciated :D

Comment: By "email add' do you mean email address? I'm sorry I'm not understanding what you're trying to find at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant.  This email address is declared somewhere on this server and doesn't exist on the AD.  How can I locate the setup/conf related to this email address.  I know it sounds vague.  Will try to clarify my question.

Comment: Could you clarify what "RT" means too?

Comment: RT is Request Tracker, a ticket logging/task tracking kit of software.

Comment: Try looking in /etc/aliases or /etc/mail/aliases

Comment: @sendmoreinfo, thank you.  That's been useful.